# How to get number of bytes written successfully?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project that convert code from C++ to C# for printer.
I replace `WriteFile()` in C++ with `SerialPort.Write()` in C#.

C#

```
public void Write(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

C++

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _In_         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

In C++ i can get number of bytes written in *lpNumberOfBytesWritten*. How to do the same thing in C#?

Answer (score 2):

In c# We can use API call like below,

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte [] lpBuffer,
uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
[In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);
```

For more information see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writefile